# Split code of one leaflet map (so that input updates of one part does not affect other part of code)

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, shinydashboard

Is it possible to split the code of a map so that a part of the map only updates if it's own input is changed?

In the reproducible example below, when selecting the "toner" tile and selecting a new station, the whole leaflet map is executed again because `addLegend` needs to be updated. Which makes the tile jump back to "OSM (default)" tile. I would like to stay at the tile I selected when I select other stations.

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

pal <- colorFactor(
  palette = "YlGnBu",
  domain = quakes$stations
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("stations", 
                  "Choose a station",
                  choices=sort(unique(quakes$stations)),
                  selected = c(10, 11))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("map")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  points <- reactive({
    quakes %>%
      filter(stations %in% input$stations)
  })
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(quakes) %>%
      addTiles(group = "OSM (default)") %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner, group = "Toner") %>%
      addLayersControl(
        baseGroups = c("OSM (default)", "Toner"),
        options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)) %>%
      addLegend("Legend", position = "topleft", pal = pal, values = input$stations)
  })
  
  observe({
    if(nrow(points()) == 0) {
      leafletProxy("map", data = points()) %>%
        clearMarkers()
    } else {
      leafletProxy("map", data = points()) %>%
        clearMarkers() %>%
        addCircleMarkers(radius = 2)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried several things, including adding `addLegend` to the `else` statement, but that does not go well. I'm new to leaflet/shiny, moving `addLegend` seemed most logic to me. I really appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I get it you were on the right track by trying to move `addLegend` to the observer. Doing so worked fine for me.

1. Move `addLegend` to `observe`
2. Before adding the legend use `clearControls` to remove any existing legend (otherwise you get multiple legends)
3. I removed the duplicated code in the `observe`
4. As far as I get it the condition `nrow(points()) > 0` is only needed to decide whether a legend should be drawn or not. For the markers it doesn't matter.

```
    library(leaflet)
    library(shiny)
    library(dplyr)
    
    pal <- colorFactor(
      palette = "YlGnBu",
      domain = quakes$stations
    )
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          checkboxGroupInput("stations", 
                             "Choose a station",
                             choices=sort(unique(quakes$stations)),
                             selected = c(10, 11))
        ),
        mainPanel(
          leafletOutput("map")
        )
      )
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output) {
      points <- reactive({
        quakes %>%
          filter(stations %in% input$stations)
      })
      
      output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet(quakes) %>%
          addTiles(group = "OSM (default)") %>%
          addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner, group = "Toner") %>%
          addLayersControl(
            baseGroups = c("OSM (default)", "Toner"),
            options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))
      })
      
      observe({
        proxy <- leafletProxy("map", data = points()) %>%
          clearMarkers() %>% 
          clearControls() %>% 
          addCircleMarkers(radius = 2)
        
        if (nrow(points()) > 0) 
          proxy <- proxy %>% addLegend("Legend", position = "topleft", pal = pal, values = input$stations)
        
        proxy
      })
    
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```